# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds when creating new object?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Here's my code, in Java. It takes in an image and changes a pixel at a time until it reaches the last pixel of the image, then it writes the image out. I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception on line 67, where I declare a new Color object:

```
Color pixel = new Color(image.getRGB(j,i));
```

I'm using UNIX to code this for a class as well, if that information is pertinent. Any idea what's happening?

```
public class SecretDecoder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    try
    {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int[] rgbOriginal = new int[3];

        if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("red"))
        {
            rgbOriginal[0] = 255;
            rgbOriginal[1] = 0;
            rgbOriginal[2] = 0;
        }
        else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("green"))
        {
            rgbOriginal[0] = 0;
            rgbOriginal[1] = 255;
            rgbOriginal[2] = 0;
        }
        else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("blue"))
        {
            rgbOriginal[0] = 0;
            rgbOriginal[1] = 0;
            rgbOriginal[2] = 255;
        }
        else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("white"))
        {
            rgbOriginal[0] = 255;
            rgbOriginal[1] = 255;
            rgbOriginal[2] = 255;
        }
        else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("gray"))
        {
            rgbOriginal[0] = 128;
            rgbOriginal[1] = 128;
            rgbOriginal[2] = 128;
        }
        else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("cyan"))
        {
            rgbOriginal[0] = 0;
            rgbOriginal[1] = 255;
            rgbOriginal[2] = 255;
        }
        else
        {
            rgbOriginal[0] = 0;
            rgbOriginal[1] = 255;
            rgbOriginal[2] = 0;
        }

        System.out.println(width);
        System.out.println(height);
        for(int i = 0; i <  height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <  width; j++)
            {
                Color pixel = new Color(image.getRGB(j,i));
                if(pixel.getRed() == rgbOriginal[0] && pixel.getGreen() == rgbOriginal[1] && pixel.getBlue() == rgbOriginal[2])
                {
                    if(args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("red"))
                        image.setRGB(j,i,Color.RED.getRGB());
                    else if(args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("green"))
                        image.setRGB(j,i,Color.GREEN.getRGB());
                    else if(args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("blue"))
                        image.setRGB(j,i,Color.BLUE.getRGB());
                    else if(args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("white"))
                        image.setRGB(j,i,Color.WHITE.getRGB());
                    else if(args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("gray"))
                        image.setRGB(j,i,Color.GRAY.getRGB());
                    else if(args[2].equalsIgnoreCase("cyan"))
                        image.setRGB(j,i,Color.CYAN.getRGB());
                    else
                        image.setRGB(j,i,Color.BLACK.getRGB());
                }
            }
        }

        File resultFile = new File("decoded_file.png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", resultFile);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like... C# or Java...

Comment: Yes, sorry. First post on this forum. It is indeed Java. Ill edit that in to my body.

Comment: Isn't args[0] the name of the program?

Comment: @Chrisky no, that's only in C/C++, in Java, the "name" of the program is always java or javaw so that would be pointless.

Comment: @Phalanges This is not throwing exception for me. But you need to pass the two parameters to your program.

Comment: Try to output the retrieved width and height of the image: `System.out.println("Dimension: " + image.getWidth() + "×" + image.getHeight());`. Try `image.getRGB(i,j);`.

Comment: Just a hunch, try `Color pixel = new Color(image.getRGB(i,j));`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the image does not start at (0, 0).

I think you're going to have to call image.getMinX() and image.getMinY() as is done [here](http://www.javawebdevelop.com/3251744/).

```
System.out.println(image.getMinX());
System.out.println(image.getMinY());
for(int i = image.getMinY(); i <  height; i++) {
    for (int j = image.getMinX(); j <  width; j++) {
```